# How to automate the process of subsetting the data with selected columns with bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I have some command for getting the column index of the columns I wanted and then cut the columns and save to a new files(subset). Here are my script for getting the column index:

```
for VAR in var1,var2;do head file.csv | tr "\," "\n" | grep -n $VAR;done
```

The output is like this:

```
1:var1
2:var2
```

and here is how I subset the file with column index

```
cut -d ',' -f1,2 file.csv >> subset.csv
```

My question is how I link this 2 parts together so I can automate the whole process? I want the second part to take the first part's output, which are column indexes as an input. So all I need to do is to give it a list of variables names and a file name. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: You made an error in typing your first "script". You shouldn't post code you haven't tried.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to turn the output of `grep` into something like `-f1,2`. Here we use `sed`+`tr`. By the way: You don't need a loop for your `grep` command. `grep` can search for multiple patterns at once:

```
cut -d, -f "$(head -n1 file.csv | tr , \\n | grep -Fn -e var1 -e var2 |
sed 's/:.*/,/;$s/,//' | tr -d \\n)" file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Socowi already presented a good solution. The only thing one might miss there is the handling of the mentioned *list of variables names*, so here's another script which takes the (comma-separated) *list of variables names and a file name* as first and second argument, respectively.

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$2
set -- $1
case $1 in *,*) eval set -- {$1};; esac
index=`for VAR; do head -1 $file | tr , '\n' | sed -n /$VAR/=; done`
cut -d, -f${index//$'\n'/,} $file
```